# What do I do with all this cheese?

Tags: cheese

Last week, a friend helped us out with a trip to Costco (long story, we didn't have time to cook, or grocery shop for a couple of days), and while she got us some really good stuff, one of the things I'm questioning is the purchase of a package of american cheese.  Can anyone suggest what to do with 120 slices of cheese?  We don't eat this often, and our church isn't having any bbq's anytime soon, so we're kinda at a loss as to what we should do with all this.  Thanks.

Comment: [Mmmmm, 64 slices of American cheese...](http://videosift.com/video/Mmmmmm-64-slices-of-American-cheese)

Comment: @Aaronut Your video can only be streamed within USA :(

Comment: @belisarius: Best I can do.  I'm in Canada, if I could find a better one I would.  I'm sure most people will get the reference anyway. ;)

Comment: @Aaronut Sorry, don't know what to search for. No cultural references to 64 bottles of beer .. err slices of cheese here.

Comment: @belisarius: http://www.snpp.com/episodes/1F01.html

Comment: @Aaronut Ahhh Ok. I understand now. Poor @Tom!

Comment: Have a ninja cheese tournament: http://www.angryflower.com/accura.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buy the packaged crescent rolls and roll a slice of cheese in each roll before you bake it...just in time for Thanksgiving! Alternately, you can roll it with a slice of meat and mini flat breads for a quick snack.

Comment: I'm definitely gonna try the crescent rolls.

Answer (score 9):

To answer the question -- grilled cheese.

To not answer the question -- freeze it.  My neighbor has an account at BJ's (another similar wholesale club), and she buys it, then freezes it in more managable portions, and just thaws it out in her fridge as she needs it.  I can't do American cheese (dairy issues), so I don't know if there's any loss of quality from the freezing, but I'm guessing in melted applications such as grilled cheese, it'd be less significant.

Comment: Given that we're talking about processed cheese, there's not much quality to begin with.  I'm giving this a pass on the culinary uses rules simply because American cheese isn't actually something I think of as a *food*.

Comment: freezing it is my suggestion, too -- the texture might change a little, but it will certainly still melt just fine when thawed.

Comment: Mmmm... grilled cheese... It's one of those things that's actually *better* when made with the pasteurized processed stuff. (The other being mac & cheese, which is much better when made with neon-orange powder than with actual cheddar. Save the good cheese for eating out of hand.)

Answer (score 2):

Freeze it. Cheese doesn't suffer too much after freezing and, after all, I guess you are going to melt this slices, so a change in the texture will not be noticeable.

I most of the time have some gratted cheese in the freeze because it is handy if I want to prepare some [gratin](http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_gratin-dauphinois_13809.aspx) or [lasagne](http://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Lasagne-alla-Bolognese.html).

[In that site](http://itscheese.com/articles/can-you-freeze-cheese) they made some experimenting with frozen cheese.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind: Mac & Cheese.  Combine, melt, mix and you've got enough to feed your entire congregation :>)